# Fancybox 2 incorrect rendering on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fancybox-2

Added fancybog gallery to my website, but it renders incorrectly on Google Chrome. Tested it out with Firefox (Win), Internet Explorer and Safari (Mac) - latest versions. The problem appears only in Chrome (also Chrome  Canary).

It displays the frame, but its not adjusted to the window. If i scroll down the frame moves. The whole window is dimmed (the picture is dimmed too), and the controls are disappeared. Also the gallery function is broken.

I'm using fancyBox 2.1.3
my code:

JS:

```
if (jQuery(".fancybox-button").size() > 0) {
            jQuery(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
                groupAttr: 'data-rel',
                prevEffect: 'none',
                nextEffect: 'none',
                closeBtn: true,
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'inside'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="assets/img/1.jpg" data-rel="listing_gallery" class="fancybox-button">IMG1</a>
<a href="assets/img/2.jpg" data-rel="listing_gallery" class="fancybox-button">IMG2</a>
<a href="assets/img/3.jpg" data-rel="listing_gallery" class="fancybox-button">IMG3</a>
<a href="assets/img/4.jpg" data-rel="listing_gallery" class="fancybox-button">IMG4</a>
<a href="assets/img/5.jpg" data-rel="listing_gallery" class="fancybox-button">IMG5</a>
```

Any idea what causes the problem? Thanks.

Comment: please paste your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Works fine for me Chrome (Windows) Version 37.0.2062.124 m http://jsfiddle.net/5qem57gm/ BTW, `groupAttr` is not a valid API option. Use the `data-fancybox-group` attribute instead of `data-rel`